# Detect if Mouse is over ListBox item or ScrollBar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a PopUp Window, which contains ListBox. In ListBox PreviewMouseUp event, I get the selected item from ListBox and close the PopUp. However, even the ScrollBar of the ListBox sends these PreviewMouseUp events, so I am not able to scroll the list without getting the PopUp closed..

How can I separate the click of an item in the list from a click of the ScrollBar?

Comment: For the user the most obvious way to *confirm* his choice will be to click button. As an alternative, you could use double-click event.

Comment: Finally I sorted this out myself - Adding ListBox inside a ScrollViewer did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the ListBox inside a `ScrollViewer` works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this event: SelectedIndexChanged on your listbox.
This event is fired when you select a new item from your listbox.

Comment: Yes, but this also fires when keyboard is used to scroll through items, so it cannot be used

Comment: Whats the matter with using the keyboard instead of the mouse?

Comment: If you carefully read my question, I mention about closing the PopUp window when value is selected, so obviously I cannot use SelectedIndexChanged to detect mouseselection, because I need to close the Popup. User has these options: a) Select value by mouse b) Select with keyboard and press Enter or Space

Comment: @Jaska Sorry for miss reading but you could use this [Clickme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.leftbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if mouse button is pressed. You could also use an else if to do something else if keyboard is used.

Comment: I already solved this by adding the ListBox inside a ScrollViewer, then the ScrollBar has it's own events and ListBox has it's own.

Answer (score 0):

can you not use the

```
 PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp
```

Event? This shouldonly firewhen you release the left mouse button and not when you scroll with the mousewheel. Or maybe its even better to use the

```
SelectedIndexChanged
```

Event of your ListBox to make sure you dont click the Mousebutton and notselecteing a ListBox Element with that click.

Edit:

Okay then why dont you handle the dbl click event or maybe better add a button and get the selected item of your ListBox when the button is clicked and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I didn't mention about the wheel, but using the scrollbar with mouse pressed